# Complex Number Integration in Java

Tags: java, math

I have A function `Func(x)` which returns a complex number.

And I need to calculate Integral of `I/Func(E^(I*x))` where x is from `Pi/3` to `Pi/2`.

How can i do that in `Java`?

Comment: Can you add some part of your code whatever you have progressed till now

Comment: Have you tried something? If you did, paste your code, and tell us where you have the error. If you didn't ... try it first, and then come to ask for your errors. We don't do Homework. Try to read the tour to do good questions --> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Have a look at [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/)

Comment: For the sake of clarity, are you using `I` as the square root of -1 and `E` as the base of the natural logarithm?  Those are generally denoted as lower case `i` or `j` in the case of the square root of -1 and lower case `e` in the case of the base of the natural logarithm.  Also, is `x` a real number or is it a complex number?  If it's complex is `Func` also an analytic function?

Comment: @andand Not necessarily when the programming language recommends that constants be in all caps.  In this case [E](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#E) (with PI right below) and [I](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html#I).

Comment: If you need an exact, symbolic result -- if you only have to solve this for a known value or values of `Func`, solve it in some symbolic computation system (e.g. [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) or [Sympy](http://sympy.org)). If you need to solve this for a variable `Func`, my first advice is to give up Java and work entirely in Maxima or Sympy. My second advice is to invent some glue code to enable a Java program to talk to Maxima or Sympy. I know it can be done for Maxima, but it is somewhat painful.

Comment: If you need a numerical result -- since the integral is actually an integral of a single real variable `x`, you can separate the integrand into real and imaginary parts and integrate those separately and then take your result as integral(real part) + I*integral(imaginary part). This is much, much simpler than trying to integrate symbolic stuff into Java ....

Comment: @Teepeemm Understood with Java... but then if that were Java code, I don't think `^` would be the correct operator in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons library provide a good support for handling complex numbers. Have a look at - [Apache commons complex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html)

Comment: I understood Apache Commons's Complex Numbers ,problem is I wasn't able to understand it Integration's

Comment: In that case, you should try it out first, then post specific issue you face - if any.

Comment: Apache Commons Math documentation says its quadrature functions are only for real functions of 1 variable.

Comment: I realize now that OP's integral is actually an integral of a real variable, so Apache Commons Math is indeed applicable (if OP is looking for a numerical approximation).