# Java - Numerical Integration of a complex function - Zeta function, Abel-Plana formula

Tags: java, complex-numbers, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis

(Note: I found a partial solution. I have pasted the test results at the end)

I am looking to numerically integrate an approximation of the zeta function. This is done through what is known as the Abel-Plana formula. The Abel-Plana formula can be used to numerically evaluate Zeta(s) for s = a + i*b.

[image]

I first wrote a program to calculate Zeta(s) for s in real. It seems to work,

```
/**************************************************************************
**
**    Abel-Plana Formula for the Zeta Function           
**
**************************************************************************
**    Axion004
**    08/16/2015
**
**    This program computes the value for Zeta(s) using a definite integral
**    approximation through the Abel-Plana formula. The Abel-Plana formula
**    can be shown to approximate the value for Zeta(s) through a definite
**    integral. The integral approximation is handled through the Composite 
**    Simpson's Rule known as Adaptive Quadrature.
**************************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class AbelMain2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbelMain();
    }

    public static void AbelMain() {
        double s = 0;
        double start, stop, totalTime;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the value of s inside the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function: ");
        try {
                s = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please enter a valid number for s.");
        }
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("The value for Zeta(s) is " + AbelPlana(s));
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = (double) (stop-start) / 1000.0;
        System.out.println("Total time taken is " + totalTime + " seconds.");
    }

    // The definite integral for Zeta(s) in the Abel Plana formula.
    // Numerator = Sin(s * arctan(t))
    // Denominator = (1 + t^2)^(s/2) * (e^(pi*t) + 1)
    public static double function(double x, double s) {
        double num = Math.sin(s * Math.atan(x));
        double den = Math.pow((1.0 + Math.pow(x, 2.0)), s / 2.0) *
                        (Math.pow(Math.E, Math.PI * x) + 1.0);
        return num / den;
    }

    // Adaptive quadrature - See http://www.mathworks.com/moler/quad.pdf
    // Used to approximate values for definite integrals
    // Parameters - a is the start of the integral, b is the end of the
    // integral, s is the double value used to evaulate Zeta(s).
    public static double adaptiveQuad(double a, double b, double s) {
        double EPSILON = 1E-6;
        double step = b - a;
        double c = (a + b) / 2.0;
        double d = (a + c) / 2.0;
        double e = (b + c) / 2.0;
        double S1 = step / 6.0 * (function(a, s) + 4*function(c, s) + 
                function(b, s));
        double S2 = step / 12.0 * (function(a, s) + 4*function(d, s) + 
                2*function(c, s) + 4*function(e, s) + function(b, s));
        if (Math.abs(S2 - S1) <= EPSILON)
            return S2 + (S2 - S1) / 15.0;
        else
            return adaptiveQuad(a, c, s) + adaptiveQuad(c, b, s);
    }

    // Returns an approximate sum of Zeta(s) through an integral aproximation
    // by Adaptive Quadrature
    public static double AbelPlana(double s) {
        double C1 = Math.pow(2.0, s - 1.0) / (s - 1.0);
        double C2 = Math.pow(2.0, s);
        return C1 - C2 *adaptiveQuad(0, 10, s);
    }
}
```

I then tried to extend this program to s in complex. It appears that the program doesn't work because I am trying to numerically evaluate a complex function through quadrature. The quadrature method that I wrote is only applicable to real-value functions as shown in [Adaptive Quadrature](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/quad.pdf). The work around I used is rather strange although it seems to work.

Here is what I wrote for the numerical approximation. I had to use a helper class in order to calculate complex numbers in Java.

```
    /**************************************************************************
**
**    Abel-Plana Formula for the Zeta Function           
**
**************************************************************************
**    Axion004
**    08/16/2015
**
**    This program computes the value for Zeta(s) using a definite integral
**    approximation through the Abel-Plana formula. The Abel-Plana formula
**    can be shown to approximate the value for Zeta(s) through a definite
**    integral. The integral approximation is handled through the Composite 
**    Simpson's Rule known as Adaptive Quadrature.
**************************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class AbelMain extends Complex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbelMain();
    }

    public static void AbelMain() {
        double re = 0;
        double im = 0;
        double start, stop, totalTime;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Calculation of the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function in the form Zeta(s) = a + ib.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function: ");
        try {
                re = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please enter a valid number for a.");
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function: ");
        try {
                im = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please enter a valid number for b.");
        }
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Complex z = new Complex(re, im);
        if ( re == 1 && im == 0)
            System.out.println("Zeta(s) is undefined for Zeta(1 + 0*i).");
        else
            System.out.println("The value for Zeta(s) is " + AbelPlana(z));
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = (double) (stop-start) / 1000.0;
        System.out.println("Total time taken is " + totalTime + " seconds.");
    }

    // The definite integral for Zeta(s) in the Abel Plana formula.
    // Numerator = Sin(s * arctan(t))
    // Denominator = (1 + t^2)^(s/2) * (e^(pi*t) + 1)

    public static Complex f(double t, Complex z) {
        Complex num = (z.multiply(Math.atan(t))).sin();
        Complex D1 = new Complex(1 + t*t, 0).pow(z.divide(2.0));
        double D2 = Math.pow(Math.E, Math.PI * t) + 1.0;
        Complex den = D1.multiply(D2);
        return num.divide(den);
    }

    // Adaptive quadrature - See http://www.mathworks.com/moler/quad.pdf
    // Used to approximate values for definite integrals
    // Parameters - a is the start of the integral, b is the end of the
    // integral, s is the double value used to evaulate Zeta(s).
    public static Complex adaptiveQuad(double a, double b, Complex s) {
        double EPSILON = 1E-6;
        double step = b - a;
        double c = (a + b) / 2.0;
        double d = (a + c) / 2.0;
        double e = (b + c) / 2.0;

        Complex S1 = (f(a, s).add(f(c, s).multiply(4)).add(f(b, s))).
                multiply(step / 6.0);
        Complex S2 = (f(a, s).add(f(d, s).multiply(4)).add(f(c, s).multiply(2))
                .add(f(e, s).multiply(4)).add(f(b, s))).multiply(step / 12.0);
        Complex result = (S2.minus(S1)).divide(15.0);

        if(S2.minus(S1).mod() <= EPSILON)
            return S2.add(result);
        else
            return adaptiveQuad(a, c, s).add(adaptiveQuad(c, b, s));
    }

    // Returns an approximate sum of Zeta(s) through an integral aproximation
    // by Adaptive Quadrature
    public static Complex AbelPlana(Complex z) {
        Complex two = new Complex(2.0, 0.0);
        Complex C1 = two.pow(z.minus(1.0)).divide(z.minus(1.0));
        Complex C2 = two.pow(z);
        Complex mult = C2.multiply(adaptiveQuad(0, 10, z));
        if ( z.re < 0 && z.re % 2 == 0 && z.im == 0)
            return new Complex(0.0, 0.0);
        else
            return C1.minus(mult);
    }

    public AbelMain(double re, double im) {
        super(re, im);
    }
}
```

The second class for Complex numbers.

```
/**************************************************************************
**
**    Complex Numbers        
**
**************************************************************************
**    Axion004
**    08/20/2015
**
**    This class is necessary as a helper class for the calculation of 
**    imaginary numbers. The calculation of Zeta(s) inside AbelMain is in
**    the form of z = a + i*b. 
**************************************************************************/

public class Complex extends Object{
    public double re;
    public double im;

    /**
        Constructor for the complex number z = a + i*b
        @param re Real part
        @param im Imaginary part
    */
    public Complex (double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    /**
        Real part of the Complex number
        @return Re[z] where z = a + i*b.
    */
    public double real() {
        return re;
    }

    /**
        Imaginary part of the Complex number
        @return Im[z] where z = a + i*b.
    */
    public double imag() {
        return im;
    }

    /**
        Complex conjugate of the Complex number
        in which the conjugate of z is z-bar.
        @return z-bar where z = a + i*b and z-bar = a - i*b
    */
    public Complex conjugate() {
        return new Complex(re, -im);
    }

    /**
        Addition of two Complex numbers (z is unchanged). 
        <br>(a+i*b) + (c+i*d) = (a+c) + i*(b+d)
        @param t is the number to add.
        @return z+t where z = a+i*b and t = c+i*d
    */
    public Complex add(Complex t) {
        return new Complex(re + t.real(), im + t.imag());
    }

    /**
        Addition of Complex number and a double. 
        @param d is the number to add.
        @return z+d where z = a+i*b and d = double
    */
    public Complex add(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re + d, this.im);
    }

    /**
        Subtraction of two Complex numbers (z is unchanged). 
        <br>(a+i*b) - (c+i*d) = (a-c) + i*(b-d)
        @param t is the number to subtract.
        @return z-t where z = a+i*b and t = c+i*d
    */
    public Complex minus(Complex t) {
        return new Complex(re - t.real(), im - t.imag());
    }

    /**
        Subtraction of Complex number and a double. 
        @param d is the number to subtract.
        @return z-d where z = a+i*b and d = double
    */
    public Complex minus(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re - d, this.im);
    }

    /**
        Complex multiplication (z is unchanged).
        <br> (a+i*b) * (c+i*d) = (a*c)+ i(b*c) + i(a*d) - (b*d)
        @param t is the number to multiply by.
        @return z*t where z = a+i*b and t = c+i*d
    */
    public Complex multiply(Complex t) {
        return new Complex(re * t.real() - im * t.imag(), re * 
                t.imag() + im * t.real());
    }

    /**
        Complex multiplication by a double.
        @param d is the double to multiply by.
        @return z*d where z = a+i*b and d = double
    */
    public Complex multiply(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re * d,this.im * d);}

    /**
        Modulus of a Complex number or the distance from the origin in
        * the polar coordinate plane.
        @return |z| where z = a + i*b.
    */
    public double mod() {
        if ( re != 0.0 || im != 0.0)
            return Math.sqrt(re*re + im*im);
        else
            return 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * Modulus of a Complex number squared
     * @param z = a + i*b
     * @return |z|^2 where z = a + i*b
    */
    public double abs(Complex z) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(re*re, 2) + Math.pow(im*im, 2));
    }


    /**
        Division of Complex numbers (doesn't change this Complex number).
        <br>(a+i*b) / (c+i*d) = (a+i*b)*(c-i*d) / (c+i*d)*(c-i*d) =
        * (a*c+b*d) + i*(b*c-a*d) / (c^2-d^2)
        @param t is the number to divide by
        @return new Complex number z/t where z = a+i*b  
    */
    public Complex divide (Complex t) {
        double denom = Math.pow(t.mod(), 2); // Square the modulus
        return new Complex((re * t.real() + im * t.imag()) / denom, 
                (im * t.real() - re * t.imag()) / denom);
    }

   /**
        Division of Complex number by a double.
        @param d is the double to divide
        @return new Complex number z/d where z = a+i*b  
    */
    public Complex divide(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re / d, this.im / d);
    }

    /**
        Exponential of a complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> e^(a+i*b) = e^a * e^(i*b) = e^a * (cos(b) + i*sin(b))
        @return exp(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex exp () {
        return new Complex(Math.exp(re) * Math.cos(im), Math.exp(re) *
                Math.sin(im));
    }


     /**
        The Argument of a Complex number or the angle in radians 
        with respect to polar coordinates.
        <br> Tan(theta) = b / a, theta = Arctan(b / a)
        <br> a is the real part on the horizontal axis
        <br> b is the imaginary part of the vertical axis
        @return arg(z) where z = a+i*b.
    */
    public double arg() {
        return Math.atan2(im, re);
    }


    /**
        The log or principal branch of a Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> Log(a+i*b) = ln|a+i*b| + i*Arg(z) = ln(sqrt(a^2+b^2)) 
        * + i*Arg(z) = ln (mod(z)) + i*Arctan(b/a)
        @return log(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex log() {
        return new Complex(Math.log(this.mod()), this.arg());
    }

    /**
        The square root of a Complex number (z is unchanged).
        Returns the principal branch of the square root.
        <br> z = e^(i*theta) = r*cos(theta) + i*r*sin(theta) 
        <br> r = sqrt(a^2+b^2)
        <br> cos(theta) = a / r, sin(theta) = b / r
        <br> By De Moivre's Theorem, sqrt(z) = sqrt(a+i*b) = 
        * e^(i*theta / 2) = r(cos(theta/2) + i*sin(theta/2))
        @return sqrt(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex sqrt() {
        double r = this.mod();
        double halfTheta = this.arg() / 2;
        return new Complex(Math.sqrt(r) * Math.cos(halfTheta), Math.sqrt(r) * 
                Math.sin(halfTheta));
    }


    /**
        The real cosh function for Complex numbers.
        <br> cosh(theta) = (e^(theta) + e^(-theta)) / 2
        @return cosh(theta)
    */
    private double cosh(double theta) {
        return (Math.exp(theta) + Math.exp(-theta)) / 2;
    }

    /**
        The real sinh function for Complex numbers.
        <br> sinh(theta) = (e^(theta) - e^(-theta)) / 2
        @return sinh(theta)
    */
    private double sinh(double theta) {
        return (Math.exp(theta) - Math.exp(-theta)) / 2;
    }

     /**
        The sin function for the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> sin(a+i*b) = cosh(b)*sin(a) + i*(sinh(b)*cos(a))
        @return sin(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex sin() {
        return new Complex(cosh(im) * Math.sin(re), sinh(im)* 
                Math.cos(re));
    }

    /**
        The cos function for the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> cos(a +i*b) = cosh(b)*cos(a) + i*(-sinh(b)*sin(a))
        @return cos(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex cos() {
        return new Complex(cosh(im) * Math.cos(re), -sinh(im) * 
                Math.sin(re));
    }

    /**
        The hyperbolic sin of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> sinh(a+i*b) = sinh(a)*cos(b) + i*(cosh(a)*sin(b))
        @return sinh(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex sinh() {
        return new Complex(sinh(re) * Math.cos(im), cosh(re) * 
                Math.sin(im));
    }

    /**
        The hyperbolic cosine of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> cosh(a+i*b) = cosh(a)*cos(b) + i*(sinh(a)*sin(b))
        @return cosh(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex cosh() {
        return new Complex(cosh(re) *Math.cos(im), sinh(re) * 
                Math.sin(im));
    }

    /**
        The tan of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> tan (a+i*b) = sin(a+i*b) / cos(a+i*b)
        @return tan(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex tan() {
        return (this.sin()).divide(this.cos());
    }

    /**
        The arctan of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> tan^(-1)(a+i*b) = 1/2 i*(log(1-i*(a+b*i))-log(1+i*(a+b*i))) =
        <br> -1/2 i*(log(i*a - b+1)-log(-i*a + b+1))
        @return arctan(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex atan(){
        Complex ima = new Complex(0.0,-1.0);    //multiply by negative i
        Complex num = new Complex(this.re,this.im-1.0);
        Complex den = new Complex(-this.re,-this.im-1.0);
        Complex two = new Complex(2.0, 0.0);    // divide by 2
        return ima.multiply(num.divide(den).log()).divide(two);}

    /**
     * The Math.pow equivalent of two Complex numbers.
     * @param z - the complex base in the form z = a + i*b
     * @return z^y where z = a + i*b and y = c + i*d
    */
    public Complex pow(Complex z){
        Complex a = z.multiply(this.log());
        return a.exp();
    }

    /**
     * The Math.pow equivalent of a Complex number to the power
         * of a double.
     * @param d - the double to be taken as the power.
     * @return z^d where z = a + i*b and d = double
    */
     public Complex pow(double d){
         Complex a=(this.log()).multiply(d);
         return a.exp();
     }

    /**
        Override the .toString() method to generate complex numbers, the
        * string representation is now a literal Complex number.
        @return a+i*b, a-i*b, a, or i*b as desired.
    */
    public String toString() {
        if (re != 0.0 && im  > 0.0) {
            return re + " + " + im +"i";
        }
        if (re !=0.0 && im < 0.0) {
            return re + " - "+ (-im) + "i";
        }
        if (im == 0.0) {
            return String.valueOf(re);
        }
        if (re == 0.0) {
            return im + "i";
        }
        return re + " + i*" + im;       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex s = new Complex(2.0, 3.0);
        Complex y = new Complex(3.0, 4.0);
        Complex d = new Complex(4.0, 2.0);
        Complex x = new Complex(1.0, 0.0);


        System.out.println(s.atan());
        System.out.println(s.divide(d));
        System.out.println(s.im);
        System.out.println(s.pow(y));
        System.out.println(s.pow(2.0));
    }

}
```

I did some preliminary testing and it seems that both the public static Complex f and public static Complex AbelPlana methods work fine. I checked these calculations against Mathematica. The method for

```
public static Complex adaptiveQuad(double a, double b, Complex z)
```

also works (for low values).

```
Calculation of the Riemann Zeta Function in the form Zeta(s) = a + ib.

Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: -12
Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 1.2
The value for Zeta(s) is 0.0900630360334386 + 0.08241454022912213*i
Total time taken is 0.014 seconds.

Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 0.3
Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: -2.1
The value for Zeta(s) is 0.4003421605328948 + 0.2570024810252463*i
Total time taken is 0.005 seconds.

Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 1
Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 2
The value for Zeta(s) is 0.598165521081844 - 0.35185471257583556*i
Total time taken is 0.005 seconds.

Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 0.5
Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 10
The value for Zeta(s) is 1.5448963436469043 - 0.1153378574814412*i
Total time taken is 0.014 seconds.

Something is clearly wrong with larger values.

Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: 24
Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta Function: -8
The value for Zeta(s) is 164561.70457820524 + 302628.94685036544*i
Total time taken is 0.003 seconds.
```

I scanned the internet and couldn't find a method for numerical integration  of complex functions. The integral for the approximation is shown in [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%28s*arctan%28t%29%29%20%2F%20%28[%281%2Bt%5E2%29%5E%28s%2F2%29]*%28e%5E%28pi*t%29%2B1%29%29%20from%20t%20%3D%200%20to%20t%20%3D%20infinity). It doesn't seem like I can use this relationship in the program (it needs to calculate the Zeta(z) for z = a+i*b anyhow).

I searched and found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#Java), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052200/complex-number-integration-in-java). Do I need to reference the [Apache Commons Math library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) to numerically integrate a complex function? I would prefer to write a method to do this myself. My current knowledge doesn't seem to be sufficient, all of the numerical integration methods that I know directly approximate real-valued functions.

I will review why my method fails for large values...

Comment: Numeric integration of real functions is based on geometric models where areas are approximated by sums of other areas (crudely spoken). - Is there anything like this for complex functions? - I've passed an exam on the theory of complex functions on a very high level but I've never heard about this.

Comment: http://www.tf.uns.ac.rs/~omorr/radovan_omorjan_003_prII/s_examples/Scilab/Gilberto/scilab07.pdf

Comment: One of the rare cases where I upvoted a question although I did not wrap my head around it in its entirety. Just two remarks: The Apache Math Library already contains a class for `Complex` numbers (and many other libraries as well, but) if you think that the Apache library can help to solve your problem, you should give it a try. In doubt, you can also look at its source code at https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=tree;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4

Comment: I found a partial solution although the Complex adaptiveQuad method is rather confusing. It is not easy to understand, let me analyze further.